# nginx rewrite rules for tweetnest

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, php-fpm

Recently I migrated my last apache to nginx (+ php-fpm). Everything works fine except tweetnest by month links (tweetnest/yyyy/mm).

tweetnest provides apache rewrite rules (`.htaccess`) which works fine OOTB

`.htaccess` for apache

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /tweetnest
 RewriteRule ^sort/?$ ./sort.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^favorites/?$ ./favorites.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^search/?$ ./search.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ./month.php?y=$1&m=$2
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ./day.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3
```

However, no example for nginx.

I managed to find this https://github.com/graulund/tweetnest/issues/37

But it is for CNAME, not exactly the same as my tweetnest use case -> `domain.com/tweetnest`.

I tried various combinations but failed to get it work.

Currently I am using the following block in nginx vhost config file

```
 # tweetnest rewrite rules
 location ~ /tweetnest {
     root /var/www/path;
     rewrite ^/sort/?$ sort.php last;
     rewrite ^/favorites/?$ favorites.php last;
     rewrite ^/search/?$ search.php last;
     rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ month.php?y=$1&m=$2;
     rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ day.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3;
 }
```

Getting 404 error when clicking on tweetnest/yyyy/mm links.

The complete vhost configuration is like below

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen   *:80;

    root /var/www/path/to/root;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    # rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.domain.com$1;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com-error.log;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        # Use upstream
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Browser cache
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
        expires 30d;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # tweetnest rewrite rules
    location ~ /tweetnest {
        # root /var/www/domain.com;
        rewrite ^/sort/?$ sort.php last;
        rewrite ^/favorites/?$ favorites.php last;
        rewrite ^/search/?$ search.php last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ month.php?y=$1&m=$2;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ day.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated ;-)

#### Update on 27 June, 2014.

Issue fixed by changing the rewrite rules as below

```
# tweetnest rewrite rules
location ~ /tweetnest {
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/sort/?$ /tweetnest/sort.php last;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/favorites/?$ /tweetnest/favorites.php last;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/search/?$ /tweetnest/search.php last;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /tweetnest/month.php?y=$1&m=$2;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /tweetnest/day.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3;
}
```

Comment: `^` indicates the start of the line.  You need to put `tweetnest/` between the `^` and the first `/` on all of your rewrite lines.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't make a diff.

Comment: I guess, you have to add tweetnest to rewrite result too.
`rewrite ^/tweetnest/sort/?$ /tweetnest/sort.php last;` and so on should work.

Comment: @alexeyten thanks but still doesn't work ;-(

Comment: Try to turn [`rewrite_log`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite_log) and look into error.log for details

Answer (score 1):

You set `root` directive inside the location. This is not a good idea. You should use the `alias` directive if you need to specify a separate location for tweetnest files.

So, if your tweetnest `sort.php` is located in `/var/www/tweetnest/sort.php`, your config should look like this:

EDIT: Modified after new information in comment below.

```
root /var/www/terry;
# tweetnest rewrite rules
location /tweetnest {
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/sort/?$ /tweetnest/sort.php last;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/favorites/?$ /tweetnest/favorites.php last;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/search/?$ /tweetnest/search.php last;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /tweetnest/month.php?y=$1&m=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/tweetnest/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /tweetnest/day.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3 last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my use case, the vhost root is `/var/www/terry` and tweetnest is a subdirectory `/var/www/terry/tweetnest`. I access tweetnest using `domain.com/tweetnest`I tried using alias, that will result in a 404.

Comment: I've modified my answer based on the new information.